# UILabel text animation with side to unlock effect

Tags: ios, animation, text, uilabel, calayer

I was wondering how do someone achieve the "slide to unlock effect" on a UILabel's text without using a static image as previously asked here.

```
// I'd like to use the uilable's current text to this sample code  but not seem to be able to do it.

    // --->  UIImage *textImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SlideToUnlock.png"];
      CGFloat textWidth = textImage.size.width;
      CGFloat textHeight = textImage.size.height;

  CALayer *textLayer = [CALayer layer];
  textLayer.contents = (id)[textImage CGImage];
  textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 215.0f, textWidth, textHeight);
  CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

  // Mask image ends with 0.15 opacity on both sides. Set the background color of the layer
  // to the same value so the layer can extend the mask image.
  maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.15f] CGColor];
  maskLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mask.png"] CGImage];

  // Center the mask image on twice the width of the text layer, so it starts to the left
  // of the text layer and moves to its right when we translate it by width.
  maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
  maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(-textWidth, 0.0f, textWidth * 2, textHeight);

  // Animate the mask layer's horizontal position
  CABasicAnimation *maskAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
  maskAnim.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:textWidth];
  maskAnim.repeatCount = 1e100f;
  maskAnim.duration = 1.0f;
  [maskLayer addAnimation:maskAnim forKey:@"slideAnim"];

  textLayer.mask = maskLayer;
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
```

Thanks

Comment: What would you use? An image generated programmatically? Would you use a different approach altogether? What's the problem with this approach that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below Project. It is a UILabel with slide to unlock animation

http://code4app.net/ios/Animated-Label/505fd71a6803fa1077000001

Comment: thanks. this is what I was looking for. however the license provided is a bit strict.

Answer (score 0):

- Top: UILabel with opaque background and clear text

  - Clear text is rendered in drawRect: func through complicated masking process
- Middle: Worker View that is performing a repeating animation moving an image behind the top label
- Bottom: a UIView that you add the middle and top subview to in that order. Can be whatever color you want the text to be

An example can be seen here https://github.com/jhurray/AnimatedLabelExample